# jquery attr() do not work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, opera, attr

I use jquery to do some thing, and I use `attr()` method to get the `id` attribute, and it works well in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE9 and Opera, some of the code is like:

```
parent = $(this).parents('.every_note');        
loan_id = parent.attr('id');
```

in the line

```
loan_id = parent.attr('id');
```

Opera said: `Unhandled Error: 'parent.attr' is not a function`, 
and in IE said: `does not support attr() method or attribute`.

But i can use this method if I test it in the browser's console ,
so anyone can tell me why？ thanks

Comment: Console log $(this) and see what does it return

Comment: I've tried the same code in IE9 and it's working fine

Comment: does it could the name "parent" problem? And when I add a breakpoint, the parent is undefined, but it is ok in chrome when i add a breakpoint, this is wired.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes IE does not like the "$" while "jQuery" does work for me. In older IEs there is another problem with global vars in combination with jQuery.

Try:

```
var parent = jQuery(this).parents('.every_note');        
var loan_id = parent.attr('id');
```

[Article about jQuery-IE-problems (german)](http://felix-geenen.de/javascript/jquery-fallen-im-internet-explorer/)

Answer (score -3):

Use

```
parent = $(this).parents('.every_note');   
loan_id = $("+parent+").attr('id');
```

Comment: What are those `+` signs supposed to mean?

Comment: parent variable contains the html element,+ used for javascript concatenation

Comment: Ah, I see. It will not work in its current form then. Did you test this before posting your answer?